# Genug pausiert oder Deine Pause ist vorbei

Tags: idiomaticity

Bei einer Anwendung möchte ich dem Benutzer sagen, dass seine Pause vorbei ist bzw. er genug gearbeitet hat. Es handelt sich dabei um eine Timerapp.

Zurzeit sind die zwei Benachrichtigungen:

> Genug pausiert!
>
> Genug gearbeitet!

Allerdings klingt das für mich nicht richtig. Wie formuliert man normalerweise solche Benachrichtigungen?

Comment: Ich würde **pause beendet** sagen.

Comment: @AdInfinitum Allerdings mit großem Anfangsbuchstaben: "Pause beendet".

Comment: @Uwe ja ja, das ist schade, dass ich den Kommentar nach fünf Minuten nicht bearbeiten kann :)

Comment: @AdInfinitum Ja, das finde ich bei SE auch lästig. Manchmal bleibt nur der Ausweg,
den Kommentar zu löschen und nochmal zu schreiben.

Answer (score 5):

Grundsätzlich ist an »genug pausiert« nichts Falsches; gelegentlich verwenden das meine Kollegen oder ich am Ende der Mittags- oder Kaffeepause im Sozialraum. Allerdings muss man es auch nicht für die ideale Lösung halten. Zum Glück gibt es ausreichend Alternativen:

> - Pause beendet!
> - Zurück an die Arbeit!
> - Die Arbeit ruft!
> - Genug entspannt!
> - u.v.m.

Answer (score -1):

*Genug pausiert* is incorrect, that's probably why it sounds wrong. *Pausiert* refers to a state, such as a game/movie that's paused.

You can use either of these:

> Pause vorbei
>
> Zurück zur Arbeit

*"Pause vorbei"* means *"Break is over"*, *"Zurück zur Arbeit"* means *"Back to work"*.

Comment: Ich sehe an "genug pausiert" nichts falsches. Auch auf einer Wanderung oder während der Arbeit kann man pausieren.

Comment: Möglicherweise ist das Missverständnis, dass *pausieren* und *Pause machen* zwar beides richtig, aber nicht dasselbe ist. Eine Theatertruppe, die pausiert, und die Pause nach dem ersten Akt ist nicht dasselbe.

Comment: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/pausieren